# Detect gaps in audio file without playing

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, audio-processing

By reading the byte array of the audio file, is there any way to find all the gaps before playing it? I am using ActionScript 3.

**What I've tried:**
When sound is playing, I can correctly find  a gap by using this code below. Where the `SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(byteArr);` fills `byteArr` with the computed FFT. See [reference](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum()).

```
isGap = true;
SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(byteArr);
for (var i:uint=0; i<256; i++)
{
    var num:Number = byteArr.readFloat();
    if (num > 0.005) 
    {
        isGap = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Never tried it, but it seems you can do the following. Load the audio, then **Sound.extract(...)** https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#extract() it into the **ByteArray** form, then just run over the whole extracted data and see if there are any gaps long enough to satisfy your criteria.

Comment: The problem is I know what to look for in the extracted bytearray.  I thought if a value from bytearray.readFloat() = 0 then there is a gap, but those values always come back greater than 0.

Comment: I have no specific knowledge about sound data, but with common sense you can tell that "gap" is a piece of data where values approximately equal (and not necessarily close to zero). I'd load a sample with such a gap and look for a place where each value differs from previous one no more than (so here we come to a definition of threshold) for the length of (so here we come to a "minimal gap" value) bytes. Also, I believe the stereo sound comes interlaced, like all odd indices are left channel and all even indices are right (or versa, the exact picture is not the point, just the idea).

Comment: examine your audio curve to identify its min <--> max do not assume it goes from zero to +1 often audio is normalized to vary from -1 to +1 .... also I would smooth out the silence determination by feeding a number of audio samples into a RMS calculation to judge ~volume~ instead of doing a test on each audio sample ... RMS is just the square add squareroot equation for a window of samples ... run that then slide the window forward in time and repeat for next set of audio samples etc... by using a RMS test instead of individual samples you minimize false positives

Comment: Thanks, but some sample code would be very helpful :)

Comment: @DTDT **(1)** Please use the `@` symbol to notify a specific user, because no-one gets notified of your responses if there are multiple commenters. Anyways... **(2)** Provide some starting code we can adjust & fix. Maybe some AS3 for loading an mp3 into a sound object and also tries the `sound.extract` part into some ByteArray. It doesn't have to work correctly (we fix that part). **(3)** If possible (but not  important) also provide a link to a testable short mp3 (with known silence points to test the code result against).